# Посчитать количество операций сделанных компилятором?

Tags: c#, алгоритм, visual-studio

Есть ли какой-то простой вариант посмотреть кол-во машинных команд, что сделал компилятор C# в VS?

Cуть в том, что мне потребовалось посчитать фактическое кол-во операций в программе, реализующий один алгоритм, используя асимптотическую оценку и программно. Я понимаю, что можно просто ввести переменную и увеличивать её значение после каждой операции, но есть ли какой-то аналогичный более простой и красивый вариант?

Comment: Посчитать то можно было бы, вот только компилятор не делает ни одной машинной команды. Код компилируется в машинный при запуске приложения с помощью JIT компилятора. Но и это, я не знаю, как сможет помочь при оценке сложности алгоритма. И добавление переменной-счетчика, тоже не знаю, как может помочь. Вы уверены, что верно понимаете смысл термина "асимптотическая сложность"?

Comment: Вам нужна асимптотическая оценка, а значит вам надо на алгоритм и размеры входных данных глядеть, а не компилятор.

Comment: Используйте профайлер для подсчёта количества вызовов функций или выполнения строк в исходном коде.

Comment: @tym32167, проверить верность теоретических оценок с помощью практических измерений - хорошая идея.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy это как то противоречит тому, что я написал?

Comment: Ваш вопрос состоит из двух параграфов. И они противоречат друг другу. Опишите подробней, что вам нужно. / Для C# есть несколько компиляторов. И очень-очень разных!

Comment: @tym32167, я возражал против утверждения что не надо смотреть на компилятор. Иногда надо. Асимптотическая оценка может быть, чаще всего, проверена на практике.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy то есть надо фокусироваться на алгоритме и входных данных, например, запускать алгоритм со входными данными и измерять скорость. Причём тут компилятор? Компилировать можно любым компилятором любой версии дотнетов.

Comment: @tym32167, это так если вы можете написать тест, время работы которого измерите. Если нет, то профилировщик выполнит для вас эту работу. В конце концов, написание специального теста - это создание кастомного профайлера для конкретного алгоритма.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy если нет возможности написать тест или нет возможности измерить его время работы - то как можно что то вообще говорить про скорость работы алгоритма? Ну и профиоировщик это не компилятор, мой комментарий был про компилятор.

Comment: Для проверки скорости алгоритма просто профилировщика будет недостаточно. То, что вы ищете - назывется бенчмаркинг, для этого есть разные либы в дотнете, например эта самая известная https://benchmarkdotnet.org/